# Powershell to SQL database

Tags: sql-server, powershell, remote-access

My initial post was how to pass data directly from the pipeline to a (remote) SQL database. Writing to a CSV then a database did not work for the amount of data I am working with - over 2 million files I am querying.

Below is the final script I came up with.  It scans a file server, filters in the pipeline,  creates a PSObject with the file attributes and then stores the attributes of the Object to variables. Those variables are then passed to the SQL query string. It's a bit cumbersome, but I could not see another way to get the file attributes read directly into the query string.

I also needed a way to run this remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).addYears(-1)
$exclusions = @(".lnk",".url",".ini",".odc",".ctx",".upd",".ica")
$connectionString = "Server=db01;Database=Files;Integrated Security=True;"
$count = 0

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

gci "D:\USERS" -Recurse | ? { 
  $_.PSIsContainer -eq $False -and
  $_.LastAccessTime -le $cutOffDate -and
  $exclusions -notcontains $_.Extension -and
  $_.length -gt "0" -and
  $_.Directory -notmatch ".*USERS\\.*\\Personal\\sysdata\\cookies"
} | % {
  $obj = New-Object PSObject
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $_.DirectoryName
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $_.Name
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty MB ("{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length/1MB))
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastAccessed $_.LastAccessTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty LastMofified $_.LastWriteTime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Created $_.creationtime
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Extension $_.Extension

  $v1 = $obj.Directory
  $v2 = $obj.Name
  $v3 = $obj.MB
  $v4 = $obj.LastAccessed
  $v5 = $obj.LastMofified
  $v6 = $obj.Created
  $v7 = $obj.Extension
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.fs01 (directoryPath,fName,fileSize,lastAccessed,lastModified,createdDate,extension) VALUES ('$v1','$v2','$v3','$v4','$v5','$v6','$v7');"
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `Invoke-SQLCmd2` you can write and read data from an SQL server database. More info [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1).

I'm not sure but I think this CmdLet does not accept pipeline input. So your best bet would be to transform your code to a `Foreach` structure and invoke the Cmdlet `Invoke-SQLcmd2` every time you want to do an `INSERT` or something else.

Something like this:

```
$CSV = Get-Content -Path "D:\FS01-USER-Files\$name.csv"
Foreach ($Line in $CSV) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd2 @SQLParams -Query "
        INSERT INTO $SQLTable 
        (FileName, Data)
        VALUES('$Line.FileName', '$($Line.Data)')"
}
```

**How can this be run with another account that has domain privileges?**

You can set up a `Scheduled Task` that runs as another user with the password stored. This task can then be triggered by other users who have RDP access to the server where the `Scheduled Task` has been created.

Comment: Does "*read data from an SQL database*" mean "*read from any relational database using SQL as the query language*"? Or do you really mean "*read from a **Microsoft SQL Server** database*"?

Comment: I believe it's only Microsoft SQL databases that are supported. If you need more info, please consult the link in the post. As I'm not the author of the function. But for my purposes it works really great!

Comment: Then you should change "SQL database" to "SQL Server database". "*SQL*" is just a query language, not a DBMS product. Every relational database is a "SQL database".