# Inserting data into sql from csv files or insert data direct from remote computer into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, powershell

I have multiple remote machines on a network that have a csv file on them stored in the same location that has been created by a powershell script.

Whats the best way to insert that data into a Microsoft Sql Server express database?

Comment: Depends on the dbms product used...

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server express

Comment: Which version of SQL Server Express? Could you please paste a portion of your CSV? Are these files identically in structure on all machines? Are the of identical structure in all lines?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Express with Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: Sample code isSystemSyncTime SystemSyncDate ComputerName
18:57:32 05-11-15 MINO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to collect all the CSV-files from all the servers to your script server. And then run the SQL `INSERT` query from the script server to put your data in an SQL table.

As described in one of my previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302048/powershell-to-sql-database/32307459#32307459) you can use this [module](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1) `Invoke-SQLCmd2` to do this.

The other way, when you don't want to collect all the CSV-files first, is running the SQL `INSERT` query from every server that has a CSV-file. To do this you have to connect to the other server and then import the module from the script server, so you can use it:

```
Import-Module -Name '\\SCRIPTSERVER\C$\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Invoke-SQL'
```

Comment: Next question is can the remote machine insert data directly into the sql database.  I would like to know a good way to insert data from a remote machine into a sql database

Comment: Answer updated, you can import the module from any server once it's installed on your script server for example.